# Vue.js cookies implementation method to control ui option?

Tags: vue.js, controls

I'd like to use vue-cookies to set up on/off switch for ui option, and I don't think I even managed to implement the control as computed setter, method, or watcher.

If cookie is false/undefined I enable text with filter for roman numerals, else I switch to Arabic numerals. I either struggle with reading data when it's method, or toggling when it's computed setter (the watcher I just don't know what's wrong with).

Comment: Show what you've tried and what's not working.

Comment: It's largely gone over iteration, what I have now is funny logic where I use Meteor.tracker as state, while this.data is just switch trigger and it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `mounted` hook to check your cookies when component is mounted and use your logic there. More info about Lifecycle Hooks here: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/instance.html#Instance-Lifecycle-Hooks

Otherwise you can set cookie into your data and use `watch` property, which leans on your cookie value. More info here: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Watchers

Comment: @ZhanKaribzhanov try to init cookie as data prop in lifecycle hooks, i.e. `mounted`.

Comment: the library was bugged, !!cookie breaked on false.